JsonSerializer deserialize correctly deserialized string, then fails to deserialize string
I was working on some Login logic for an application and had the following code:
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SignInResult>(json)!;

It was working and deserialized the SignInResult correctly. I proceeded out of the area of code and was working on some other portion. Two hours later I ran the application again and went to go through the login logic and things were now broken. A little bit of troubleshooting as to where things were failing, it came down to the above code as the culprit of things no longer working.
I can clearly see in the debugger that the string that is passed through is giving one out put and the deserialization is returning a different output.
JSON (string):
{
    "succeeded": true,
    "isLockedOut": false,
    "isNotAllowed": false,
    "requiresTwoFactor": false
}

Result

{Failed}  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult
IsLockedOut   false   bool
IsNotAllowed  false   bool
RequiresTwoFactor false   bool
Succeeded false   bool
Static members

I have tried
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SignInResult>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true })!;

which still returned the same results.
I then tried restarting the computer, and tried this again. Still the same result.
The next day, the same thing happens.
I cleared the browser - same thing.
I came here because I am clearly at a loss of how to fix this without over engineering a solution that should be working.
Does anyone have an idea as to why this stupidly simple code is no longer working, when it clearly shows that the string coming back says true but the deserialization converts that to false?

Post SignInResult's code. I have a suspicion.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

SignInResult.Succeeded has a protected setter. It will be ignored in deserialization using System.Text.Json.

...probably indicating it wasn't intended to be used as a dto.

As other have already figured out, the class is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult.

I understand that it has a protected setter, and see that it should never have worked in the first place, but it did.  Which is what is annoying as it worked and I was able to move towards the other code I was working on since I had a good result.

By default, System.Text.Json will not deserialize properties that have protected setters. That is the case with SignInResult.Succeeded, which looks like this:
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a flag indication whether the sign-in was successful.
    //
    // Value:
    //     True if the sign-in was successful, otherwise false.
    public bool Succeeded { get; protected set; }

I am going to assume that you have a good reason for passing this result around and for serializing/deserializing it. Solutions to the non-public setter involve modifying the source class to decorate it with attributes, or otherwise changing the class, which is not an option for you. One thing you could do is have a corresponding data transfer object you control, which you then convert to a SignInResult. For example:
public record class SignInResultDto(
    bool Succeeded, 
    bool IsLockedOut, 
    bool IsNotAllowed, 
    bool RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    public static explicit operator SignInResult(SignInResultDto result)
    {
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return SignInResult.Success;
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return SignInResult.LockedOut;
        }

        if (result.IsNotAllowed)
        {
            return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return SignInResult.TwoFactorRequired;
        }

        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }
}

You could then use that as follows:
var json = @"{
    ""succeeded"": true,
    ""isLockedOut"": false,
    ""isNotAllowed"": false,
    ""requiresTwoFactor"": false
}";

var signInResult = (SignInResult)JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SignInResultDto>(
    json, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });

Console.WriteLine(signInResult.Succeeded); // true


This is working.  I guess a little over enginnering is not too bad.
